# Using different fonts in win32 application

Tags: c, winapi

How do I use a font already installed on my computer in my win32 application? I want to use more fonts than those already existing in win32. Here is my code right now where I want to use the Liberation Mono font:

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(window);

const TCHAR *font_name = TEXT("Liberation Mono");

LOGFONT lf = {0};
lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(24, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, _countof(lf.lfFaceName), font_name);

HFONT newFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

SendMessage(window, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)newFont, TRUE);

char str[256] = "Test";

TextOutA(hdc, 0, 0, str, strlen(str));

DeleteObject(newFont);
ReleaseDC(window, hdc);
```

But instead this just gives me the standrad win32 font. I've also tried the following solution, replacing `SendMessage()` with `SelectObject()`, but it gives me the same results.

```
HDC hdc = GetDC(window);

const TCHAR *font_name = TEXT("Liberation Mono");

LOGFONT lf = {0};
lf.lfHeight = -MulDiv(24, GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, _countof(lf.lfFaceName), font_name);

HFONT newFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);

SelectObject(hdc, &newFont);

char str[256] = "Test";

TextOutA(hdc, 0, 0, str, strlen(str));

DeleteObject(newFont);
ReleaseDC(window, hdc);
```

Comment: `wcscpy_s`-ing from a `TCHAR*` doesn't look right. It may or may not work depending on your project configuration. And if it doesn't work then C will not complain about mismatching pointer types.

Comment: @IInspectable I tried changing `wcscpy_s` to `_tcscpy_s`, but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Not that it'd make a difference, but you should be using wide character strings (e.g. `wchar_t*`). At any rate, you never observe the return value of any API call. It's entirely likely that one of them fail. Certainly, you do not want to delete a font object while it's still selected into a device context.

Comment: `TextOutA` is not concerned with a font set with `WM_SETFONT`, only with the font selected into the device context. Your `SelectObject` didn't work because you put the `&` in front of `newFont`. On top of that, you should not be deleting your font while it's being used by either a dialog (via `WM_SETFONT`) or a device context ([via `SelectObject`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130306-00/?p=5043)).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you! I checked the return value of SelectObject(), and it turns out it failed.

Comment: Side note, you can declare `const wchar_t *font_name = L"Liberation Mono";` you don't need `TCHAR` and those `t` macros. Painting is usually done in response to `WM_PAINT` followed by call to `hdc = BeginPaint... EndPaint`